# JavaScript/jQuery timer for method to be invoked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple animation using jQuery on hover method.  The problem is if the user hovers over the same image twice the method is re-invoked. How can you put a "timer" on a method from being invoked twice.

Comment: Please show your existing code. There are (at least) two or three simple fixes, but it would be easier for us to add them to your code than to write a full example from scratch.

Comment: Consider posting a live, working version of the problem you are facing in JSFiddle, JSBin, or a similar online live coding web site in order to assist users in understanding your problem.

Comment: That I will do! - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `element` and `otherElement` with your selectors, of course.  And the other basic info can be changed to your spec.  But this is how you can do it.

```
var going = false;
$('#element').hover(function () {
    if (going === true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        going = true;
        $('#otherElement').animate({
            'font-size': "96px"
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            complete: function () {
                going = false;
                $(this).css('fontSize', '24px');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

### [Live JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVFf7/)

This will only fire the animation if your animation isn't already going.  It will not stop the animation to start a new one.  if you need that, just put `.stop()` before `.animate()` and remove all the `if/then` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When hovering on the image use the following idea:

```
//Global variable
var now = null;
var SECONDS_TO_HOLD = 60; //assume you want to hold it for 60 seconds

//On Hover method:
if (now == null){
   now = Date.now();
   //Invoke hover method
} else {
   var diff = Date.now() - now; //time diff in milliseconds
   if (diff > (SECONDS_TO_HOLD *1000)){
       now = Date.now();
       //Invoke hover method
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `:animated` selector (http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check if animation is running !

```
$("body").on("mouseenter",".animation:not(:animated)", function(){
    $(this).animate({left:"+=50"}, 5000);// Or any code to animate
});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/LVw7L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Running the animation once with http://api.jquery.com/one/
or unregistering / removing the event handler might be an option http://api.jquery.com/one/